# Svelte, only re-render an item in list, not the entire list

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, urql

Both with `svelte-apollo` (https://github.com/timhall/svelte-apollo/issues/19) and `@urql-svelte` (https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/issues/704) I'm having an entire list re-render instead of just an element re-render.

#### Reproduction steps:

- go to REPL: https://codesandbox.io/s/urql-svelte-list-rerendering-uwsvn
- click a button
- every button re-render; so the entire list re-render itself
- I expect it re-renders only the button I clicked

If I read here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-options, I understand that by using:

> immutable={true} — you never use mutable data, so the compiler can do simple referential equality checks to determine if values have changed
>
> immutable={false} — the default. Svelte will be more conservative about whether or not mutable objects have changed

If you see the example they are changing the `todos` array as we are also doing with `urql`:

```js
let todos = [
  { id: 1, done: true, text: 'wash the car' },
  { id: 2, done: false, text: 'take the dog for a walk' },
  { id: 3, done: false, text: 'mow the lawn' }
];

function toggle(toggled) {
  todos = todos.map(todo => {
    if (todo === toggled) {
      // return a new object
      return {
        id: todo.id,
        text: todo.text,
        done: !todo.done
      };
    }

    // return the same object
    return todo;
  });
}
```

Why it doesn't work with my REPL `todos` example?

Is `todos` a new array at the end?

Comment: When you say "every button re-renders; so the entire list re-render itself", how did you ascertain that?

Comment: Did you see the "flash" effect on each buttons here: https://codesandbox.io/s/urql-svelte-list-rerendering-uwsvn?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to clarify. The flash is triggered by `afterUpdate`, that doesn't mean the component was re-added to DOM, that would trigger in `onMount`.

Comment: Ok. I think I have some confusion about "re-adding", "re-rendering" and "re-painting" and what else?